# Need to take average of long, strangely formatted set of data in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples, average

So I have a large set of data that looks like this

```
[('ART', [100, 234, 830, 304]), ('MATH', [600, 1400, 300, 340]), ('HISTORY', [2010, 300,   400, 600])]
```

How would I turn this into a set of data that I can average the numbers inside of and then sort? I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Is this a string of characters that you are looking to parse into a data structure that you can work with?  Or do you think this is valid Python?  (it's close, but not quite)

Comment: You want to end up with `[('ART', 359), ('MATH', 660), ('HISTORY', 827)]`?

Comment: By "Close but not quite" he means that it would either have to be `('A', [1, 2])` or `{'A': [1, 2]}`. You either have a dict with curly braces and a colon, or a tuple with parenthesis and a comma.

Comment: Shoot, I typed it in wrong. Let me edit it now, it's valid Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for:

```
input = [('ART', [100, 234, 830, 304]), 
         ('MATH', [600, 1400, 300, 340]), 
         ('HISTORY', [2010, 300, 400, 600])]
```

this:

```
print sorted( ( (k,sum(v)/len(v)) for k,v in input ), key=lambda t: t[1] )
```

prints:

```
[('ART', 367), ('MATH', 660), ('HISTORY', 827)]
```

Comment: Replace `input.iteritems()` with just `input` and it works with the edit.

Comment: Python automatically sorts a list of tuples by the first elements in the tuples, then by the second elements and so on...so you don't really need the lambda.

Comment: Perfectly Pythonic,  Dan.  Nice to see.

Comment: @Paolo, The `key` is used to sort the numbers.  The OP didn't say in the question whether to sort by topics or numbers; it kinda sounded like numbers, though.  If the desire was to sort by topics then you're totally right about not needing the key.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to sort by numbers to see which department was receiving the most money.

Comment: Nice code.  Personally, I would have made a function called `mean()` that does `sum(v)/len(v)` because I think it is a bit easier to understand that way.  But that's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @Dave Trecmar Oh ok, so ignore my first comment :-)